# Illegal parameter number in definition of \test and other errors in Beamer Poster

Tags: beamerposter

I need help troubleshooting errors in my [Beamer Poster](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pdhddcqdcbss) (accessible on Overleaf). Most of the errors are of the following forms:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \test.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe.
```

Oddly the code compiles and produces the desired output, but I can't get rid of these errors. My code was adapted from this [poster](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d03e0f71813395b83bef020), which doesn't have said errors. I have tried looking at the deltas between the two posters to find the source of the errors with no success.

Comment: Wow, you're right! Please put this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When TeX complains about an "Illegal parameter number in definition", it has just read a macro parameter character `#` that either isn't followed by `1`, `2`, ... `9`, or the used number is outside of the parameter range of the current definiton. (In your document this definition is hidden somwhere in the `block` environment.)

As you are trying to typeset a literal `#` character in this case, e.g. in `#zhu`, just escape it as `\#`.

Answer (score 5):

If you came here looking for a potential cause to the error message `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate` and you are using `beamer` and `knitr`, then chances are that you forgot to declare the relevant frame as `[fragile]`.

Simply replace `\frame` or `\begin{frame}` by `\frame[fragile]` or `\begin{frame}[fragile]` respectively.

Comment: Way simpler than the other answer (I didn't even have any explicit `#` anywhere) and spot on!